# Open jquery dialog from another dialog and pass values via ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a jquery dialog that capture user input (open PLVoceInput.aspx page in jquery dialog), which are used thereafter (by posting them PLVoceOutput.aspx page) in order to compute some values on serverside and display them in another dialog.

---

```
$("#divPLVoiceInput").dialog(
             {
                 bgiframe: true,
                 autoOpen: false,
                 draggable: true,
                 modal: true,
                 position: 'center',
                 width: 400,
                 height: 200,
                 title: 'Input P&L',
                 open: function(event, ui) {
                     $(this).load("PLVoceInput.aspx?customertype=ex");
                 },
                 buttons: 
                    [
                        {
                            text: "Ok",
                            click: function() {                                   
                                var v1=$("#tbSubsidizeVal").val();
                                var v2 = $("#tbSubsidizeSims").val();
                                var v3 = $("#tbSimCost").val();
                                var v4 = $("#tbOtherCostsSim").val();
                                var v5 = $("#tbLPs").val();
                                var v6 = $("#tbSalesComm").val();
                                var v7 = $("#tbContractLength").val();
                                var v8 = $("#tbPreTaxDiscountRate").val();
                                $("#divPLVoiceOutput").css('display', 'block');
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "PLVoceOutput.aspx",
                                    //type: "POST",
                                    data: { 
                                        valSubsidizeVal: v1,
                                        valSubsidizeSims: v2,
                                        valSimCosts: v3,
                                        valOtherCosts: v4,
                                        valLP: v5,
                                        valSalesComm: v6,
                                        valContractLength: v7,
                                        valPreTaxDiscountRate: v8
                                        }
                                    });
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                $("#divPLVoiceOutput").dialog("open");
                            }
                        },
                         {
                             text: "Cancel",
                             click: function() {
                                 $(this).dialog("close");
                             }
                         }
                     ]
             });
        $("#divPLVoiceOutput").dialog(
             {
                 bgiframe: true,
                 autoOpen: false,
                 draggable: true,
                 modal: true,
                 position: 'center',
                 width: 600,
                 height: 500,
                 title: 'Detalii P&L',
                 open: function(event, ui) {
                     $(this).load("PLVoceOutput.aspx");
                 },
                 buttons: [
                    {
                        text: "Ok",
                        click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                    }
                        ]
             });
```

---

The problem is that the second dialog opens the aspx page twice, first with parameters passed, and second without any parameter, so the data displayed is not correct. What should I change in my code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```
$("#divPLVoiceInput").dialog(
             {
                 bgiframe: true,
                 autoOpen: false,
                 draggable: true,
                 modal: true,
                 position: 'center',
                 width: 425,
                 height: 250,
                 title: 'Input P&L',
                 open: function(event, ui) {
                     $(this).load("PLVoceInput.aspx?customertype=ex");
                 },
                 buttons:
                    [
                        {
                            text: "Ok",
                            click: function() {
                                $("#divPLVoiceOutput").css('display', 'block');
                                var inputData = 'valSubsidizeVal=' + $("#tbSubsidizeVal").val() +
                                    '&valSubsidizeSims=' + $("#tbSubsidizeSims").val() +
                                    '&valSimCosts=' + $("#tbSimCost").val() +
                                    '&valOtherCosts=' + $("#tbOtherCostsSim").val() +
                                    '&valLP=' + $("#tbLPs").val() +
                                    '&valSalesComm=' + $("#tbSalesComm").val() +
                                    '&valContractLength=' + $("#tbContractLength").val() +
                                    '&valPreTaxDiscountRate=' + $("#tbPreTaxDiscountRate").val();
                                $("#divPLVoiceOutput").dialog({
                                    bgiframe: true,
                                    autoOpen: false,
                                    draggable: true,
                                    modal: true,
                                    position: 'center',
                                    width: 600,
                                    height: 500,
                                    title: 'Detalii P&L',
                                    open: function(event, ui) {
                                        $(this).load("PLVoceOutput.aspx?" + inputData);
                                    },
                                    buttons: [
                                        {
                                            text: "Ok",
                                            click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                                        }
                                            ]
                                });
                                $("#divPLVoiceOutput").dialog("open");
                                $("#divPLVoiceInput").dialog("close");
                            }
                        },
                         {
                             text: "Cancel",
                             click: function() {
                                 $(this).dialog("close");
                             }
                         }
                     ]
             });
```